# Colours on bandwidth bar in Tor Network Status

Tags: exit-relays, bandwidth

I see there are exit nodes listed at http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/, but there are some colours on the Bandwidth bars (green/pink, black).

What do they represent? Do they represent how much of the bandwidth is currently being used?

Comment: Asked @blutmagie: https://twitter.com/qbi/status/635776817933250560

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding the color coding is as follows:

- [image] is for relays which have more than 20000 KB/s bandwidth.
- [image] is for relays which have more than 10000 KB/s bandwidth.
- [image] is for relays which have more than 5000 KB/s bandwidth.
- [image] is for relays which have more than 3000 KB/s bandwidth.
- [image] is for relays which have more than 2000 KB/s bandwidth.
- [image] is for relays which have more than 1000 KB/s bandwidth.
- [image] is for relays which have more than 0 KB/s bandwidth.

Maybe there are more colors for relays which have more than 50000 KB/s bandwidth. Currently there is no such relay. So I can't verify this.